# How to sum two mysql fields in php

Tags: php, laravel, sum

Im beginner in PHP and I try make this work.
I bought a ready script and trying change and learn.
I have a row like this

```
{!! $profile->likes()->where('like_type', 1)->count() !!}
```

That code sum all "1" in database and show the result.
I want just add "+" another filed to this result also. the filed is called like_plus.

I tried this

```
{!! $profile->likes()->where('like_type', 1->count() + 'like_plus') !!}
```

The Like_plus field contain number from 1-1000 where Like_type contains the number 1 or 2.

I want the code do the count first and then + Like_plus numbers in DB.

Comment: Manipulating likes on a website, are we? ;-)

Comment: Yes. But its not facebook, I bought a simple script and trying make changes, edit and learn. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
**{!!  $profile->likes()->where('like_type', 1)->count() +  $profile->likes()->where('like_plus', 1)->count() !!}**

Comment: Hi
This working only if the Like_plus field in DB has value "1".

But when I put value "1000" in Like_plus in DB it not sum it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to sum up the count of the `like_type` is 1 to `like_pluse` value to that relevant `like_type`

you can do it like this,

`{!!  $profile->likes()->where('like_type', 1)->count() +  $profile->likes()->where('like_type', 1)->like_plus !!}`

Hope this helps.